# UEFI hybrid mode win7 and ubuntu installation issue

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

i have HP 430G2 laptop in which windows 8 is preinstalled. I need to install dual boot with windows 7 and ubuntu. In bios there are three options.

1. legacy mode : here i can able to install windows 7 but while installing ubuntu it doesnot detect windows partition
2. uefi hybrid mode : here i can able to install windows as well as ubuntu but grub doesnt come it directly goes to windows. i tried boot-repair but still no success here is link of boot-repair for details http://paste.ubuntu.com/12192594/
3. uefi native mode : here i cannot able to install windows 7 itjust hangs

Comment: While your question is on topic on AU, since it's about Ubuntu on top of Windows and EFI BIOS, I suspect, that you'll get better answers over at [SU], since it covers such a broad range of technologies.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 you need to enable legacy BIOS mode. After that boot from the Windows 7 installation disk and delete all partitions while installing so that entire disk is empty. Then add a new partition and it will automatically create a new partition table. Install windows 7 and then boot Ubuntu IN BIOS MODE (explore the boot optons) and install it alongside windows 7.

Comment: If you want Windows 7 in UEFI mode, you have to copy to flash drive & make some modifications to move EFI boot files so they can be seen by UEFI. If you install Windows in BIOS mode on gpt drive, it does not correctly convert drive to MBR(msdos). It leaves backup gpt partition table and then Linux tools see both MBR & gpt. You must use fixparts to remove backup gpt data.